# PHP and MySQL SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I have an MySQL table with a field which is filled with a sentence and I'd like to get only the first word of the sentence.
After I've the first word I'd like to email out it with a form.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence_field`, ' ', 1) AS `firstWord` FROM `table`");
  $iresult = $_POST[$result];
```

Of course it doesn't work. I don't know why. How should I use the $_POST in PHP?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_query. It returns a statement HANDLE, not the value you're requesting in the query. You need to `fetch` a row first.

Comment: Thank you. My knowledge is really limited when about mysql and php.

Answer (score 1):

First, please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli).

Second, you're not returning anything from the query. It will not be in the `$_POST` array. You need to get the info in the result, one way is by fetching an array -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence_field`, ' ', 1) AS `firstWord` FROM `table`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```